# MdDialog - possible to hide instead of closing

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2, mddialog

I would like to hide my `MdDialog` instead of closing it (to not have to re-create costly resource every time)

Is it possible to just hide it?

This is how I open it:

```
 openLocationPicker() {
  const dialogParams: UserPickLocationDialogParams = {
    locationName: this.locationName,
    geoLocationString: this.latitudeLongitudeControl.nativeElement.value
  }
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserPickLocationComponent, {
    height: '470px',
    width: '600px',
    data: dialogParams
  }).afterClosed().subscribe(returnVal => {
    // ...
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it's not possible. Please look at this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5162).